Как и нужно ли изучать подкапотную .NET(.NET Core)?
На данный момент моя цель - обучится на ASP.NET Core разработчика(до этого я изучал .NET Framework, но решил сменить свои планы).
Ключевой вопрос заключается в том, нужно ли мне изучать саму платформу .NET, на которой насколько я понимаю базируется ASP.NET. И если да, то как? Для .NET Framework написана книга Джеффри Рихтера "CLR via C#", но аналогичных для .NET я не нашел. Да и в открытом источнике я не нашел методичек для написания проектов для .NET на c#.

Да не так уж сильно .NET от .NET Framework отличается. Учите по любой книжке, потом некоторые коррективы просто нужно будет внести - некоторые библиотеки поменялись (например, для доступа к Web), добавились какие-то классы, но в целом концепция не сильно поменялась. Так что берите любые источники и начинайте учить. Потом доучитесь немного на конкретно .NET и всё.

ASP.NET базируется на .NET. В свою очередь .NET Framework считается устаревшим, хоть на нем и работает большое количество сайтов и приложений. Стоит ли учить платформу .NET? Всё зависит от ваших задач и целей, PHP разработчику не обязательно знать C++, но без С/С++ он не напишет расширения для PHP. Здесь аналогично, вам необходимо понимать базовые принципы работы самой технологии .NET, включая управление памятью, механизм сборки мусора (GC), работа с самим сборщиком приложения и асинхронными задачами. Это повысит ваш уровень как разработчика, но не всегда в этом есть смысл, так как большинство вещей за вас сделает компилятор/сборщик и сама платформа .net
